# Use jQuery grep to return list of cities

Tags: jquery, json, grep

A sample of the json file I'm using...

```
[
  {
    "store":"Albertsons",
    "address":"2950 College Drive",
    "city":"Baton Rouge",
    "state":"LA",
    "zip":70808
  },
  {
    "store":"Albertsons",
    "address":"7515 Perkins Road",
    "city":"Baton Rouge",
    "state":"LA",
    "zip":70808
  },
  {
    "store":"Albertsons",
    "address":"4060 Ryan Street, South ",
    "city":"Lake Charles ",
    "state":"LA",
    "zip":70605
  },
]
```

What I'd like to do is populate a select form field with the city options... i.e.

```
<select id="city">
    <option>Baton Rouge</option>
    <option>Lake Charles</option>
</select>
```

I've figured out how to filter by all items that match the state of "LA", but I'd like to just have an array of the city names without repeats.

Comment: You'll end up w/ ambiguity in the cases where different states have cities with the same name.  e.g, http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Springfield

Comment: I'm actually filtering by State first, and then then city... Just didn't want to post the entire thing on here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you want to iterate over each object in your JSON array and pick out a unique list of city names. Assuming the city names are clean data (e.g. "Lake Charles" will always be "Lake Charles" and not something like "LAKE_CHARLES"), you can do it like this:

```
var cities = []; 

$.each(JSON, function(index, item) {
  var city = item.city;
  if(cities.indexOf(city) == -1) {
    cities.push(city);
  }
});
```

Comment: Perfect! Just what I needed!

Answer (score 0):

I use the [TexoTela jQuery Select plug-in](http://www.texotela.co.uk/code/jquery/select/) for managing select contents and am pretty happy with it.

First, you'll want to create an array of the values that you want, so assuming your array of city information is in an array called cities, we iterate over the JSON array and add the items like this:

```
jQuery.each( cities, function( i, val) { $("#mySelect").addOption(val.city, val.city ); } );
```